# How to use Selenium webdriver select date on below URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=sh

I find the element by ID 'txtShareholdingDate' and then I tried use "send_keys('201 8/10/24') not work

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your exact code along with some clarifications for *"not work"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readonly` attribute means that you cannot set the value of text field with `send_keys` method.

If you don't need your script to simulate user-like behavior, you can implement `JavaScriptExecutor` as below

```
input_field = driver.find_element_by_id('txtShareholdingDate')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value="2018/10/24";', input_field)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```

If you need to select date as user do:

```
import time

input_field = driver.find_element_by_id('txtShareholdingDate')
input_field.click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[@class="year"]//li[.="2018"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[@class="month"]//li[.="10"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[@class="day"]//li[.="24"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```

P.S. You also might need to use [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of `time.sleep(1)`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait 

input_field = driver.find_element_by_id('txtShareholdingDate')
input_field.click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//b[@class="year"]//li[.="2017"]'))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//b[@class="month"]//li[.="11"]'))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//b[@class="day"]//li[.="22"]'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```

Comment: where can I see it is readonly? I cannot search the readonly in the source file. Thanks

Comment: @KennethYeung , After you make right-click on input field and select "Inspect Element" you'll see that HTML contains `readonly` attribute: `<input name="txtShareholdingDate" value="2018/10/27" id="txtShareholdingDate" class="input-searchDate active" data-reset="2018/10/28" readonly="readonly" type="text">`

Comment: `time.sleep()`s? 4 of them? You should hang your head in shame... ;)

Comment: @JeffC , I know it looks awful :) But waiting for options to be clickable is not enough - more complex condition should be applied... and since the issue is in *sending keys* I guess solution with sleeps is OK :)

Comment: Why wouldn't waiting for clickable be good enough here? There is no `.sendKeys()` here except for the one that OP used that didn't work in this case.

Comment: Ah.. nm. I forgot about the site. Clicking on the first triggers the update on the second and so on... you would need to add some logic like wait for stale on the next object to be sure it's loaded.

Comment: @JeffC , Hm... Actually now it's working with just `EC.element_to_be_clickable` while on other computer the date remains the same and I was not be able to set new date...